# Unhandled exception after execute

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm trying to make a gray image more bright, the code did compile normaly but no change in the seconde picture, and an error message `Unhandled exception ...` showed up after that the execute is done. Here is a piece of my code:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("mra.jpg");
    if (!img) {
        printf("Error: Couldn't open the image file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    //IplImage* new_image = getlargersize(img);

    double Min , Max ;
    Min = Max = 0 ;
    Max_Min (img , &Min , &Max);
    cout<<"the max value in the picture is :"<<Min<<" and the minimum value is :"<<Max<<endl ;

    IplImage* img2 = eclaircir(Min ,Max ,img);

    cvNamedWindow("Image:", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("Image2:", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Image2:", img2);
    cvShowImage("Image:", img);

    cvWaitKey(0);

    cvDestroyWindow("Image2:");
    cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
    cvReleaseImage(&img2);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    return 0;
}    
void Max_Min(IplImage* temp , double *min , double *max ){
    CvScalar pix ; 
    for (int i = 0 ; i < temp->height ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < temp->width ; j++){
            pix = cvGet2D(temp , i , j); 
            if ( pix.val[0] >= *max ){
                *max = pix.val[0];
            }
            if ( pix.val[0] <= *min){
            *min = pix.val[0];
            }
        }
    }
}

IplImage* eclaircir (double min , double max , IplImage* image){
    double temp = max - min ;
    CvScalar pix ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < image->height ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < image->width ; j++){
            pix = cvGet2D(image , i , j); 
            pix.val[0] = ( pix.val[0] - min)*255 ;
            pix.val[0] = pix.val[0]/temp ;
            cvSet2D(image , i , j , pix );
        }
    }
    return image ;
}
```

Comment: To determine why you get an exception it would obviously be useful to know *what* exception you get. Also you should format your post so that it's readable (there are buttons above the edit window that you can click for formatting).

Comment: In Visual Studio there is an option to let the debugger break on exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You say you use C++ in your tags, but use the C interface of opencv. Why? The C++ interface is far friendlier.
- There are opencv functions for what your functions are doing. http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#cv-minmaxloc for min and max and http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=scaleabs#convertScaleAbs to scale the image values.
- Your access violation is probably because you free your image twice. Your `eclaircir` returns the input image, so `img` and `img2` point to the same IplImage. One more reason to use the c++ interface.